# Pivot on multiple aggregated columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I cannot wrap my head around the following issue. My table structure:

```
ID Type Price Currency
1   A    100    USD
1   B    200    EUR
1   C    300    CAD
2   A    400    EUR
2   B    500    EUR
2   C    600    USD
```

I need to get the following result:

```
ID   A  A_Currency B    B_Currency  C C_Currency  
 1  100    USD     200    EUR      300    CAD
 2  400    EUR     500    EUR      600    USD
```

At this point I was able to successfully produce table without currencies like this:

```
select ID, p.A, p.B, p.C from 
(select ID, Price, Type from MyTable) as x
pivot(Max(Price) for Type in 
(A, B, C)) as p
```

And it works great. But now I'm really lost on how to add Currency for each type. I tried to put it in select but then it doesn't work and PIVOT doesn't accept multiple columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select ID
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( values ( concat(A.Type,'_Currency'),A.Currency)
                             ,( A.Type,cast(A.Price as varchar(50)))
                     ) B(Item,Value)
      ) A
 Pivot (max(Value) for Item in ([A],[A_Currency],[B],[B_Currency],[C],[C_Currency]) ) p
```

**Returns**

```
ID  A     A_Currency    B     B_Currency    C     C_Currency
1   100   USD           200   EUR           300   CAD
2   400   EUR           500   EUR           600   USD
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user194076 Happy it helped